# How to seal very old concrete to hold water?

Tags: concrete, waterproofing

I have an antique home-made concrete birdbath. It no longer holds water. How can I seal the bowl so it will hold water again? Tried swimming-pool paint in the past but it didn't work.

Comment: Usually there needs to be a crack for concrete to leak water, cracks big enough to leak are not good.  If concrete is deteriorated enough, probably should be just replaced.  If wanting to repair probably need epoxy and/or fibreglass plus  epoxy to seal.

Comment: You could place a glass pie plate, or some other water holding vessel, in the bird bath.

Comment: Is swimming pool paint the same as a concrete waterproofing paint like Damtite? If not, you may want to try that.

Comment: Polyurethane for the win!

Answer (score 1):

**Wax?**

I would try rubbing the basin with beeswax.  Maybe you already have some?   On a hot day it should soften up and fill cracks.  It is cheap.  It is safe for birds.  It will look ok.    If it does not work you have done no lasting damage.  If it does work you can do it again when it starts to leak.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't mentioned if there is a crack.  If there is one, you need to fill/repair it.  No amount of paint is going to help with that.

If there are no cracks then any exterior paint would work.  And swimming pool paint is tougher and can be more elastic.  So it should have worked.

My suspicions are

- There is a crack
- There is more evaporation, perhaps some shade from the sun has disappeared.
- You have more energetic birds there now.